# Problem upgrading a service on a trial account

Tags: administration, trial

I created a trial service for one of our customers, and when I try to upgrade it with the latest version of our service I get the flowing error message:

[image]

The new trial is on **NA22 server** (contains SalesForce Release: **Winter '16 Patch 16.3**)

I am doing these upgrades for a while now without any problems.

Comment: Sometimes we've found that some packages are unavailabe on some servers, and they're definitely not available for a short time window right after they are published. Perhaps you need to try again in 15-30 minutes. If the problem persists, I would open a support ticket with Salesforce

Comment: 10x, I think that I will try to create a new trial on a different server and see how the upgrade  goes

Answer (score 3):

As +mkorman suggested in his comment, some servers are not capable to upgrade service packages. In my case, it was NA22.

I tested the same upgrade on NA34 and the upgrade went well.